How To Set Screen Resolution Of TinyCore On GNS3 Really High?
In GNS3, I added a Firefox to the topology. It was installed on a TineyCore VM on Qemu. When I open the VM, the Max screen resolution that is available is 1024x768 which is very small for my 4K monitor. I tried a lot of things including "-vga std" option as described in the following SE SU Post among other stuff with no luck. As you can see the post is pretty old, and maybe there is more stuff to try now.
Also, I installed Xorg but did not know where to go after that as nothing happened or was added to the VM.
The Xvesa option in the control panel is dimmed out.
All work was through the GUI as I am a newbie when it comes to Linux.
Also, I tried to find out something similar to VMware tools but did not find anything that fit the situation.
Any Ideas?
The target resolution is at least: 1920 x 1080
P.S. I use GNS3 VM.

